# Powershell compare files with directory

Tags: powershell

I have a directory that contains 5 file names txt1 txt2 txt3 txt4 txt5. I also have a file that contains 3 file names txt1 txt3 txt5.  I need to overlay the directory with txt2 txt4 since those 2 files are not in the file.  I used compare-object get-child item get-content but this gives me txt2 txt4 txt5.  I also have not been able to overlay the direcory content?  How do I get just txt2 txt4 and output that to the directory

Comment: From your explanations I couldn't get even a vague idea about what you were trying to achieve, sorry. But it seems to have something to do with TXT files and directory listings, so I suppose `Get-Content`, `Get-ChildItem` and `Out-File` cmdlets may be what you're looking for.

Comment: This code worked $objDir = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\"
$objFile = Get-Content "C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt"
Compare-Object $objDir $objFile | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} How do I remove the items that were found in the Compare-Object from "C:\Users\Bruce\Serena\"